# Automatically logging into remote PHP website, using windows network logins

Tags: windows, php, iis, ldap, authentication

We've got an externally hosted PHP website running on a Digital Ocean server.

We've got a windows network hosted internally.

--

We're aware when the PHP application is running on IIS within the same network, we can enable a module which will share the user credentials with the application for authentication.

However is this possible to automate the login process when the 2 servers are completely separate?

Answer (score 1):

No. Your network login depends on access to active directory, which the external server likely does not have, though you COULD do something with replicating to Azure AD and then going against that one - but that is QUITE complicated and requires significant changes to your infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

While TomTom is right in principle about the Windows entities being seperate therefore you cannot use the credentials, you could do a workaround:

You could provide user certificate based logins. Since certificates are stored in the users browser you could automate the login that way. All major browsers support this.

IIS even has an option for this built in:
Client Certificate Mapping Authentication

See the official docs:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/clientcertificatemappingauthentication

This method works without the server bing part of the AD. You will however need to manage the client certificates on the IIS server.